# "Floor-leveling compound" for a Kohler Tresham shower base

Tags: shower, self-leveling-concrete

I have recently purchased a Kohler Tresham shower base with bench. I read the directions very carefully, and at step 4 (you can see the guide here: https://www.us.kohler.com/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/1161835_2.pdf )
it says to use "mounds of floor-leveling compound at the base feet."

This must be a mistake, because everywhere I look online, floor-leveling compound is a very thin compound that will run like liquid. There would be no way to make it into mounds.

So my question is, what product should I really use to make self-leveling mounds like this that will provide an adequate sub-base for this shower? Please let me know what brand and name. Please also check out the link above for the instructions; it's pretty short and you'll see #4, which is where I'm confused.

Comment: I agree with you:  "mounds of floor leveling compound" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm thinking MAPEI 4-to-1 Mud Bed Mix 55-lb Indoor/Outdoor Floor Patch is the one to use. It says it's "Ideal for floating shower bases."

Comment: I typically use this combination when setting shower bases and other fixtures like whirlpools etc. Set a layer of tar paper in place, followed by a layer of expanded metal lath like what is used under true stucco and plaster work, securely nailed down with roofing nails. Then mix up the appropriate amount of type S masonry cement to go over the entire surface, and thick enough to get under the floor of the base or tub. Settle it in place carefully using a level to check your progress. I am leaving this as a comment since it is not what Kohler recommends. It will work though.

Comment: I typically use this combination when setting shower bases and other fixtures like whirlpools etc. Set a layer of tar paper in place, followed by a layer of expanded metal lath like what is used under true stucco and plaster work, securely nailed down with roofing nails. Then mix up the appropriate amount of type S masonry cement to go over the entire surface, and thick enough to get under the floor of the base or tub. Settle it in place carefully using a level to check your progress. I am leaving this as a comment since it is not what Kohler recommends. It will work though.